# Reference vector paths in code?

Tags: android, svg, onclicklistener, vector-graphics, xml-drawable

I have an SVG image of a dartboard and I recently converted it to a vector using vector asset studio. I'm trying to replicate the functionality of this dartboard shown [here](http://djave.co.uk/free-svg-dartboard/).

The only problem I'm having is trying to replicate on click listeners to certain parts of the board since it's just one image. I've tried researching into splitting the vector or imageview into divs and referencing the names inside of the .XML file but nothing came up. Would it be possible to reference the vector paths in code and display the name of the path when a onclick listener is implemented (IE s19)? Or is there a different way to approach this problem?

how dartboard.xml is structured:

```
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="300dp"
android:height="300dp"
android:viewportHeight="774.0"
android:viewportWidth="787.0">
<group android:name="singles">
    <path
        android:name="s19"
        android:fillColor="#F7E9CD"
        android:pathData="M328,561.9c-2,-0.8 -3.9,-1.7 -5.8,-2.6l66.1,-138.9c2,0.8 4.2,1.5 6.4,1.9L374.7,574.8C358.6,572.6 343,568.3 327.9,561.9zM358.7,696.9l13.4,-102.2c-17.8,-2.5 -35.2,-7.3 -51.9,-14.3c-2.2,-0.9 -4.4,-1.9 -6.6,-2.9l-44.3,93.1c3.6,1.7 7.2,3.3 10.8,4.8C305.3,686.1 331.7,693.3 358.7,696.9z"/>
    <path
        android:name="s14"
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M215.2,362.7c2.2,-16.1 6.6,-31.7 12.9,-46.7c0.8,-2 1.7,-3.9 2.6,-5.8l138.9,66.1c-0.8,2 -1.5,4.2 -1.9,6.4L215.2,362.7zM93.1,346.7l102.2,13.4c2.5,-17.8 7.3,-35.2 14.3,-51.9c0.9,-2.2 1.9,-4.4 2.9,-6.6l-93.1,-44.3c-1.7,3.6 -3.3,7.2 -4.8,10.8C103.9,293.3 96.7,319.7 93.1,346.7z"/>
```

My game activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.blue.darts.GameActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/dartboard"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may come across this, it seems impossible to reference anything from vector asset studio's created vector. Your best bet would be to use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and display the SVG by converting it to HTML. From there, you can manipulate the local HTML however you like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the OP correctly, you need direct access to the path information of a static resource. Android's resources are great for creating machine readable static resources but in the process they become rather opaque. I would suggest that you translate the SVG file directly into code. There are tools, such as [almosr/android-svg-code-render](https://github.com/almosr/android-svg-code-render), to help you achieve this. Once you have the [Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) objects you can then use [Path#op](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#op(android.graphics.Path%2C%20android.graphics.Path.Op)) to intersect and [Path#isEmpty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#isEmpty()) to test for hits.

Although, not directly related there is also [PathMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html) that can be used to trace the path.

There no build instructions for the project I referenced, so here's what I did, YMMV:

```
git clone https://github.com/almosr/android-svg-code-render.git
cd android-svg-code-render
curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/caverock/androidsvg/1.2.1/androidsvg-1.2.1.jar
mkdir classes
javac -cp androidsvg-1.2.1.jar -sourcepath src -d classes src/android_svg_code_render/Main.java
jar cvfm android-svg-code-render src/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C classes .
java -jar android-svg-code-render input.svg -o output.java
```

I can then take the code from `output.java`, and have my way with it... The generated code isn't pretty but it works!

Answer (score -1):

I was able o refrence various parts of SVG in code for this I kept those svg in asset and loading it form there using [https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg]

[java svg parsing code ]

I just make some inner classes public and hold svg xml parse objects in list when user click at some part in svg Using the touch coordinate which svg part was clicked